# Rails Noob Emergency: How To Restart Server/Application? (Rails,Nginx, Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application which needs changes right now, and it's in production mode so no changes will be reflected until I restart the server, right?

My developer left on holiday 5 minutes before i discovered a surprise bug, so I have to fix it, but I need to restart the server... :(

I don't know how to do it... Can I login via SSH and issue a command to restart the server and application successfully?

PS I don't know what application server I'm running...

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly - just pay a real rails developer for an hour's worth of time to get this sorted out for you. There are just way too many variables here for us to walk you through the process.

Comment: Calling your developer seems like a good idea.  But if you provide the nginx configuration, we might be able to point you in the right direction..

Comment: Wish I could... she and the whole team left for presidents day holiday, and they don't provide phone support. Thanks for trying guys... I realize it is very vague :/

Answer (score 2):

If you have access (ssh or physical) to the server and the directory (you have permissions to actually access and modify files in them), and your Rails application is being served via Passenger (also known as mod_rails. There's a good possibility it is), you can do the following to make Passenger reload the Rails application. This won't restart the webserver, so don't worry if you have anything dependant on it.

```
touch {rails_app_root_directory}/tmp/restart.txt
```

Then you just need to reload the Rails application webpage so Passenger can do its thing, and there you have it, your Rails application is restarted.

Comment: Hey so, how did it go?